# Redux createStore source code - infinite loop risk on the enhancer recursive's callback part ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, redux, callback

I'm working currently on Redux.js. Loving reading the sources codes, I have immediately dived on the Redux source code.

Reading [the createStore code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js), I have fallen on the following code :

```
export default function createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) {
  if (typeof preloadedState === 'function' && typeof enhancer === 'undefined') {
    enhancer = preloadedState
    preloadedState = undefined
  }

  if (typeof enhancer !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof enhancer !== 'function') {
      throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.')
    }

    return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState)
  }
```

Does this loop of the createStore code should end as an infinite loop ? Cause recursively, the enhancer call itself the createStore function. So I see two scenario in this boilerplate : 
- Either because the enhancer is not defined the function end in an error
- or all it's great and the function return again the createStore, and again and again...

How do you analyze this snippet ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if `typeof preloadedState !== 'function' && typeof enhancer === 'undefined'`, the function will do the rest stuff.

Then, when we call `enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState)`, the enhancedCreateStore gets `enhancer === 'undefined'`

When we call `createStore(reducer, preloadedState)` if and only if `preloadedState === 'function`, we will finally call enhancedCreateStore(reducer, undefined, undefined)

That's why it will not end as an infinite loop.